# Importing Spatial Data from Oracle (12+) to HDFS using NiFi

Tags: oracle, spatial, apache-nifi, oracle-spatial

I am trying to migrate data from a Oracle Database (12+) with NiFi to HDFS. The processors "QueryDatabaseTable" and "ExecuteSQL" cant seem to handle geometry data type (SDO_GEOMETRY).

I'm getting the error 
"Unkown SQL Type 2002, cannot be converted to avro type"

When alternatively converting the data type to a long string using the "sdo_util.to_wktgeometry()" function, doesnt seem to be possible resp. for the first processor and the second gives the error :
"SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY() illegal character"

Does anybody have tips about migrating Geometry data types from Oracle (12+)by NiFi? A line string is enough information from the Geometry Object (for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine NiFi does not know how to handle any kind of object types defined in relational databases. And obviously much less understanding complex types like spatial types. Even if it did understand object types, you would be left with something hard to use since it would expose the internals of the type and you need a deep inspection of the Oracle manuals to decode the content in order to use the information.

The simplest is definitely to get the spatial types in a serialized string or binary notation. You have a choice between multiple notations and two approaches to fetch those:

**Using object type methods:**

Important: note that you **must** use a table alias in order to invoke object methods!

*WKT:*

```
SQL> select c.location.get_wkt() from us_cities c where city='New York';

C.LOCATION.GET_WKT()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POINT (-73.943849 40.6698)

1 row selected.
```

*GML:*

```
SQL> select c.location.get_gml() from us_cities c where city='New York';

C.LOCATION.GET_GML()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-73.943849,40.6698 </gml:coordinates></gml:Point>

1 row selected.
```

*GeoJSON:*

```
SQL> select c.location.get_geojson() from us_cities c where city='New York';

C.LOCATION.GET_GEOJSON()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-73.943849, 40.6698] }

1 row selected.
```

**Using functions:**

*WKT*

```
SQL> select sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(location) from us_cities c where city='New York';

SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(LOCATION)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POINT (-73.943849 40.6698)

1 row selected.
```

*GML*

```
SQL> select sdo_util.to_gmlgeometry(location) from us_cities c where city='New York';

SDO_UTIL.TO_GMLGEOMETRY(LOCATION)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-73.943849,40.6698 </gml:coordinates></gml:Point>

1 row selected.
```

*GeoJSON*

```
SQL> select sdo_util.to_geojson(location) from us_cities c where city='New York';

SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON(LOCATION)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-73.943849, 40.6698] }

1 row selected.
```

In those examples I show only points. Geometries can of course be more complex: lines, multi-lines, polygons, multi-polygons, polygon with voids. Also 3D structures: surfaces and solids ...

For those geometries that are points, you can just extract the X and Y coordinates straight from the objects. Again note the use of **aliases**.

```
select city, c.location.sdo_point.x longitude, c.location.sdo_point.y latitude 
from us_cities c;

CITY                            LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
New York                       -73.943849    40.6698
Los Angeles                     -118.4112  34.112101
....
Sioux Falls                      -96.7301  43.544201
Simi Valley                     -118.7513   34.26305

195 rows selected.
```

For other geometries (lines etc) then you need to pass via a text serialization.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. The problem for me was forgetting the aliases but ended up learning so much more thanks to your comment !

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Maybe you want to upvote my answer ? :-)